# move_uploaded_file not working but no error

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have been having an issue with my code, specifically with the move_uploaded_file.  I changed the folder I keep the images in's permissions to 777 to make sure it wasn't a problem with the permissions.  I also read a php manual on how to use move_uploaded_file of w3schools.com.  I have run out of ideas on how to upload my image to a folder using php.  Please help.

Here is the portion of the code with the move_uploeaded_file:

```
<?php
    if (@$_GET['action'] == "ci"){
        echo "<form action='account.php?action=ci' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'><br />
        Available file extention: <stong>.PNG .JPG .JPEG</stong><br /><br />
        <input type='file' name='image' /><br />
        <input type='submit' name='change_pic' value='Change' /><br />
        </form>";
        if (isset($_POST['change_pic'])) {
            $errors = array();
            $allowed_e = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');

            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $file_e = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $file_s = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

            if(in_array($file_e, $allowed_e) === false) {
                $errors[] = 'This file extension is not allowed.';
            }

            if ($file_s > 2097152) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be under 2MB';
            }

            if (empty($errors)) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '../images/'.$file_name);
                $image_up = '../images/'.$file_name;
                $check = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usename='".@$_SESSION['username']."'");
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($check);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)) {
                    $db_image = $row['profile_pic'];
                }
                if($query = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE users SET profile_pic = '".$image_up."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'"))
                    echo "You have successfuly changed your profile picture!";
        } else {
                foreach($errors as $error) {
                    echo $error, '<br />';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: There are several places where you use `@` to suppress errors. You should remove those, see what errors appear, and fix all of them for real. It's possible your script is dying for other reasons.

Comment: @Anoopsaju <br /> is the proper way to close tags like that.

Comment: @larsAnders I will try that soon.

Comment: @larsanders It didn't seem to show any errors of any sort.  Am I supposed to add something in the code to show errors?

Comment: Is your images folder located one step up from the php location?? Also what happen when you upload a different file type?

Comment: @SameerJain The images are stored in a folder in the root directory.  The script is stored in the root folder.  Also, if I do a file of a different type, the code stops it and says that the extension type is not allowed.  I coded that part and it is not a part of the bug.

Comment: If the script is in the root folder, then the path to images should be `images/`, not `../images/`. That's going up one level above the root folder before looking for `images`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the last chunk of the code, slightly rewritten. `move_uploaded_file` returns a boolean, so we can test if it's true or false by setting up a variable $result:

```
        if (empty($errors)) {
            $image_up = 'images/'.$file_name;
            $result = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $image_up);

            if($result){
                //this line had a typo usename -> username
                //Also, you should change this over to using parameters and binding values ASAP. This leaves you open to hacking.
                $check = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".@$_SESSION['username']."'");
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($check);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)) {
                    $db_image = $row['profile_pic'];
                }
                $q = "UPDATE users SET profile_pic = '".$image_up."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
                if($query = mysqli_query($connect, $q)){
                    echo "You have successfuly changed your profile picture!";
                    }
            } else {
                echo "Upload failed.";
            }
    } else {
            foreach($errors as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br />';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not very good with security, as you can see.  What are binding values?

Comment: Check out [the docs on parameterized queries with mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Okay, I will check it out.  Anyways, thanks for the quick fix!  You don't harshly criticize me like some people do.